# Cross Domain CORS and Images

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using AWS S3 and Cloudfront to deliver images to my sites/domains.

I've been looking at AWS S3 CORS and I wanted to ask if I limit the domains will this restrict other domains from access my images.

If I was to set the following on a Bucket that contained images would this stop other domains from access the images within the bucket or do images operate differently to under resources under CORS.

```
<AllowedOrigin>http://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
```

Essentially I would like to restrict my images to my sites only.

Also I heard you must include the Cloudfront as another AllowedOrigin for this work - Can someone confirm this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CORS is a policy enforced by a browser. Its not going to prevent users from downloading images from your cloudfront distribution.

You have two options.

1. Make all your files private and provide access via signed urls. Cloudfront wont really cache images in this case however.
2. The other option is to configure cloudfront to forward all headers, and use a bucket policy to limit access based on referrers. You can get around this, but it would prevent most casual hotlinking.